# Pull MIN and MAX prices from database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all (*) the rows from table1, table2, table3.. but I need to select the MIN and MAX price from table 2 within this INNER JOIN. I've read up on how to do this, but how do I do this within an INNER JOIN, and how do I display it in a PHP variable.

**Initial Problem:** How do I display the min and max values once I pull them.. (e.g `$Result['MinPrice']`, `$Result['MaxPrice']`).

Here's my query:

```
$Query = mysql_query("
   SELECT      *
   FROM        table1
   INNER JOIN  table2 ON table1.UserID = table2.UserID
   INNER JOIN  tables3 ON table2.DeviceID = table3.DeviceID
   WHERE       table2.DeviceID = '$GetDeviceID'
");
```

Here is the tables structure:

**table1 = usersinfo**

```
UserID   UserFirstName     UserLastName    UserDisplayName
1        John              Doe             John D.
```

**table2 = listings**

```
ListingID  UserID   DeviceID
11         1        2
```

**table3 = devices**

```
DeviceID
2
```

Comment: Tell us what the problem is. No point in trying to figure out the problem from the query...that will lead to a lot of different ideas and most likely none of them will match your true problem. ;)

Comment: How do I display the min and max values once I pull them.. (e.g $Result['MinPrice'], $Result['MaxPrice']).

Comment: Take a look at the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator

Comment: You don't obtain any maximum or minimum values with your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do what you're asking in this way you can use the query that is displayed below.  This does, however, return a lot of duplicate rows if you have multiple rows returned when querying.  Try it and see if it works.

```
$Query = mysql_query("
    SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.*,
           MIN(table2.price) as minny, 
           MAX(table2.price) as maxxy
    FROM   table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.UserID = table2.UserID
    INNER JOIN tables3 ON table1.DeviceID = table3.DeviceID
    WHERE  table1.DeviceID = '$Something'
    GROUP BY table2.ListingAskingPrice
");
```

Then get this value by doing `$result['minny'] and $result['maxxy']`

Comment: Ahhhh, so you're assigning the min, max to a name, minny and maxxy.. that's what I needed! Thanks sir. I saw some examples were doing group by, but it wasn't working.

Comment: I called them minny and maxxy just to make it easier for you to call them later on and avoid confusion.  It's not 100% necessary but a bit of minny/maxxy in your code is always fun :)

Comment: Uhm...when did aggregation functions started working together with non-grouped fields? I'm fairly sure the query won't work this way.

Comment: Haha yeah I know the names are arbitrary, but it could be fun!

Comment: Till, by aggregation functions you're talking about MIN(), MAX() ? I'm not sure, but GROUPING was not working.

Comment: The problem is that MIN() and MAX() (and other aggregation functions) work on a set of records. Without a `GROUP BY` there is no set of records to work on. The DBMS basically doesn't know for which group of records it should calculate the values. I'm pretty sure this will only work with a subselect.

Comment: Not without knowing the structure of your tables. Maybe add them to the question.

Comment: I just added the basic elements of the tables I'm using to INNER JOIN.

Comment: Added GROUP BY listings.ListingAskingPrice

Comment: Thanks for the comments and improvements guys.  I have updated the original answer, can you confirm that it works @ChristianRankin?